# I can't add a space on my output on python

Tags: python

I want a space on the Farhan Sadik and Snigdho

[image]

I tried this many times on spacing `Name`, `Name2`, `Welcome` but there is no result.

Comment: Next time, include your code directly in the the question.

Comment: add +" "+, where you want space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you concatenante your strings with no space between them.

You can do:

`print("Hi", name1, name2, welcome)`

or:

`print("Hi " +  name1 + " " + name2 + " " + welcome)`

Comment: #ThunderPheonix Thanks

Comment: @FarhanSadikSnigdho Don't forget to accept answer and close the subject

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve this, adding a space:

```
Name + " " + Name2 + " " + third_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(Name + " " + Name2 + " " + "WELCOME")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Value of Name value of name2 WELCOME
```

> If **comma**(**,**) is used in the place of **" "** it will also give the same output (**as above**)

The above code prints the value of **name** and a space **(" ")** and again **name2** and a space **(" ")** and the string **"WELCOME"**.

> In the same way if you use **\n** in the space of **" "** you will get the output of the string or variable next to the **\n** in a new line. For example:

```
print(Name + "\n" + Name2 + "\n" + "WELCOME")
```

**Output:**

```
Value of Name
Value of Name2
WELCOME
```

> In the same way if **\t** is used in the place of **\n** it will print the variable or string next to it after a **tab** space, like:

**Output:**

```
Value of Name      Value of Name2       WELCOME
```